# Run the server specific tasks in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

which module is used to implement the server specific tasks with nodejs server.

Ex: User have their own credits. The Server needs to add 10 more credits to the user every day.

For this scenario what are the modules used for this type of implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [Node Cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron), it's available on `npm` and it allows you to schedule tasks that execute periodically.